# Prevent Android Reset

Tags: android, reset

We do short-term rentals on cell phones and tablets.  You need a tablet for a week, you can come to us and we rent it too you.  What happens, is at the end of the week (or weeks) you need to return it.  Often the person renting doesn't return it (various reason), but now it is stolen property.  We have an application that we load and can send a command to that locks the device.  Or we can program the app to allow x-days and then lock (like a parking meter).  Once locked, it requires a password to unlock.  This works, but it only works if the user hasn't already reset the device back to factory.  If we load the application and rent it to someone for 2 weeks (as example), we find that often the renter will reset the device back to factory.  Various reasons they do it, mostly they are playing around with it and just want to start over.  Or if their time is up, it locks and then they pay for another rental period and we give them the password to unlock it.  In this case, they now know we have a rental meter running.

We can root the device and install the application as a system application, but chasing down rooting tools and playing 'cat and mouse' with vendors trying to prevent rooting is too much labor.

What I need, is there a way to put a password on the factory reset in the Android settings?  I do realize that most MFG's of devices allow you to press buttons and reset but that I can live with.  What I need is a way not to have the reset button in the settings of the Android so easily executed.  Anyone have a way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest that u make use of fine folks at Cynogenmod and use their code to make sure that no one can do a factory reset. Even if it does, u can make sure factory reset sets up ur renter meter as well. But with rooting and mod installation being a breeze in Android, I dont think that its impossible to crack

Comment: You'd need to patch the boot loader, which probably rules out most devices currently on the market. Merely disabling factory reset in settings is easier, as long as you can get AOSP (or CM) working on the device.

Comment: These are good ideas but it requires rooting.  The ACER ICONIA 500 and now the Toshiba Thrive have removed rooting by changing the ability to flash (fastboot) the device therefore making loading custom ROM difficult.  In other words, you cannot load Cynogenmod with out flashing the ROM which is usually used to root.  It seems MFG's don't want you rooting so they are plugging the holes as fast as you can find them (cat and mouse). So rooting and flashing really isn't what I'm looking for.  Also, if you just add Cynogenmod the device still keeps pulling OTA updates and nagging you to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

As i see, as tablets as android phones have both unique id, and imei (the phones) google gets the phone's imei, you can see it they register this. Until now they don't keep tracking a device once it is hard reseted, so you've got nothing to do. The cloud policy's change is the real solution for this problem. Imagine if the bigger providers like facebook and google, etc. would ask for an authorization when a user reports lost or stolen to the original owner this problem wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

What you might need if you are renting for a particular software, is a kiosk mode app. This can be achieved easily by making the program schedule itself for 2 or 3 seconds in the future when it's killed. Other than that modding the OS is not going to be easy.

Comment: Kill isn't an issue.  The app is dormant and wakes up every two hours and on day changes.  It is really just a parking meter application.  But, like I said, if you factory reset because you're just wanting to start over or the parking meter runs out and you pay for another period, the renter will look for the application and resets the device.

Comment: Maybe your problem is not just software, but legal. Ask a lawyer about including a non "resetting the device" policy

Comment: I also have an application that you load on a phone and it uses the changes in GPS to determine how fast you are going.  If you are moving more than 3 miles per hour (or what you set it to), then it turns off chat and the phone (other than 911).  I load it on my teenagers phone to stop them from talking and texting while driving.  I also record the speed and GPS to determine how fast they are driving.  I would like to sell this application, but I cannot have the teenagers hitting factory reset and wiping it gone.  The app would have to be installed via the market place.

Comment: No legal issue, I own the phone/tablet so I can do whatever I would like.  I own it, you are renting it.  No legal issues.  But putting it in writing tell you that you cannot do it is of little value.  It then becomes a civil matter and to costly to take you to court.  Half the time the person that rents it even goes as far as to say it was stolen.  The list goes on.  I lost 30% of phones I rented until I installed the APP.  But, ignorance of not hitting the reset button is all I have now to keep the app loaded.

Comment: In other words, paying an attorney hundreds of dollars to enforce a no reset policy on a phone/tablet worth 200-300 dollars doesn't make much sense.  Also, the only reason you rent a phone/tablet is because you cannot afford one and getting a legal settlement is worthless in these cases.  Anyway, nice idea, but it's sort of not cost affective.

Comment: Well, then the problem is on your business model, since you don't want to root the phone, or flash it, etc, nor enforce a policy. Any trick you could pull off with android can't overcome a google search to wipe the phone. IMHO

Comment: I would flash if the OEM would allow it, but they do not.  They are locking the devices making rooting difficult.  Also, anything can be hacked.  I know that 99% of my customers would never figure out how to root a phone/tablet.  But, my wife, which cannot even spell 'PC' could figure out that press the reset button just might clear it.  Secondly, if I sell the application I cannot be rooting every model.  My cell phone app that turns off the phone and text messaging works great.  But, I cannot support rooting on all the different phones.  All I want to do is make it difficult to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try storing the data of the application on the SD card?

This storage will not get deleted unless you do a wipe.

Comment: But the application don't start after factory reset and reboot so the storing data is useless.

Answer (score -1):

Its easy really. Just get a particular brand of phones for the business..like a Samsung galaxy gives u the option of a factory reset password..only for factory reset..  No password...no factory reset via settings. U alrdy said u cud liv wit hard reset

Comment: can you please correct your spelling? it is not a message that you are writing to your wife or someone.